# Turning Filepath Strings into Markdown Links

Tags: vim

I have a long list of file paths formatted like so:

```
* (00-atoms/images/AI-004-image-2x1.md)
```

These are delimited by new lines.

I would like to change these to markdown links, using the filename (sans dashes and sans the file path type) as each individual path's title:

```
* [AI 004 image 2x1](00-atoms/images/AI-004-image-2x1.md)
```

All of these filepaths are two levels deep, but the first two levels are variable:

```
* (00-atoms/forms-and-feedback/AFF-001-text-field.md)
* (01-molecules/event-text/MTE-006-event-address-bar-unordered-amenities-list.md)
```

Additionally, file names can have can tildes in them like so:

```
* (01-molecules/forms/MF-001-input-with-form-label~error-message.md)
```

I'm looking for a way with Vim (via a macro or string replacement) to format this file in the way I need it formatted. I have gone through a number of tries with string replacement and macros but have struggled to get this right. Does anyone see anything unique about these paths that might help me with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
:%s!^\* \zs([^()]*/\([^()/]\+\)\.md)!\='[' . tr(submatch(1), '-', ' ') . ']' . submatch(0)!
```

Idea:

- Run a `s!!!` substitution command on all lines (`%`)
- The pattern to replace is `^\* \zs([^()]*/\([^()/]\+\)\.md)`, matching

  - `^` - beginning of line
  - `\*` - an asterisk and a space
  - `\zs` - mark the official start of the match (everything up to this point is not replaced)
  - `(` - a left paren
  - `[^()]*` - 0 or more non-paren characters (this matches the directories in the path)
  - `/` - a slash
  - `\(` - start of capturing group 1
  - `[^()/]\+` - 1 or more non-paren / non-slash characters (the basename part)
  - `\)` - end of capturing group 1
  - `\.md` - the file extension ".md"
  - `)` - a right paren
- The replacement part is `\='[' . tr(submatch(1), '-', ' ') . ']' . submatch(0)`, meaning

  - `\=` - the rest of this is to be evaluated as an expression, not a string
  - `submatch(1)` - the contents of the first capturing group, i.e. the basename of the file (without the `.md` extension)
  - `tr(..., '-', ' ')` - transform all dashes in the string to spaces
  - `'[' . ... . ']'` - concatenate `[` and `]` characters in front / behind
  - `... . submatch(0)` - append the whole matched string

This turns `* (foo/bar-baz.md)` into `* [bar baz](foo/bar-baz.md)`.

Input:

```
* (00-atoms/images/AI-004-image-2x1.md)

* (00-atoms/forms-and-feedback/AFF-001-text-field.md)
* (01-molecules/event-text/MTE-006-event-address-bar-unordered-amenities-list.md)

* (01-molecules/forms/MF-001-input-with-form-label~error-message.md)
```

Result:

```
* [AI 004 image 2x1](00-atoms/images/AI-004-image-2x1.md)

* [AFF 001 text field](00-atoms/forms-and-feedback/AFF-001-text-field.md)
* [MTE 006 event address bar unordered amenities list](01-molecules/event-text/MTE-006-event-address-bar-unordered-amenities-list.md)

* [MF 001 input with form label~error message](01-molecules/forms/MF-001-input-with-form-label~error-message.md)
```

Comment: Wow. Incredible. Learned a lot from this, thank you so much.

Comment: The chances of me writing that on the fly (as opposed to recording a macro) are very slim... but nice!